# Passing all slots in a single expression in svelte component

Tags: svelte

how can I pass all slots at once? (think liked {children} in React...}
currently, my code looks like that -

```
<script>
  import Modal from 'components/Generic/Modal.svelte';
</script>

<SmartModal
        {...$$restProps}
>
    <slot name="header"></slot>
    <slot></slot>
</SmartModal>
```

but I don't want that. I want to have a single expression for all slots...

Comment: did you try looping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set multiple slots at once, but a single slot can contain arbitrary content, so there really is no point in having two slots directly follow each other. Just use one slot and pass in multiple elements.

(For named slots, if you want to avoid a wrapper element, you can use [`<svelte:fragment>`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-svelte-fragment).)

Comment: I am relying on other developers' work, and I have to be able to wrap their components and add functionality, and I can't dictate the design principles to them.  In React, you can wrap a Component and pass %100 of the props so this is a reasonable expectation